# Parse large CSV files and compare the data

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

Is there any CSV parser available which I use in C# and compare the CSV files?

scenario: 
I got multiple CSV files and each CSV file has couple of million rows. I should load CSV and complete the comparision as fast as possible. :)

CSV File1:

```
Account Amount
1234    1
9999    66
```

CSV File2:

```
Account Amount
1234    2
9999    66
```

CSV File3:

```
Account Amount
1234    1
9999    66
```

CSV File4:

```
Account Amount
1234    10
9999    66
```

After comparing the output looks like

```
Account File1Amt    File2Amt    File3Amt    File4Amt    Match?
1234    1           2           1           10          No
9999    66          66          66          66          Yes
```

Comment: There is nothing I know of built into C# or available to do this exact task. If you have access to a database (SQL Server, MySql etc.) you could load this in the db and run the report with a single query. Depending on how you code this and the machine resources you may be able to load all CSV files into dictionaries and produce the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use a db or you don't have enough machine resources you could create the report using a dictionary object, something along the lines of:

```
public void CreateAccountReport()
{
    Dictionary<int, AccountReport> accountReportCollection = new Dictionary<int, AccountReport>();

    //read in file 1 and add records to dictionary...

    //read in files 2,3,4 and update dictionary (when reading in file 4 set bool match)
}

public class AccountReport
{
    public int AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public int File1Amt { get; set; }
    public int File2Amt { get; set; }
    public int File3Amt { get; set; }
    public int File4Amt { get; set; }
    public bool Match { get; set; }

    public AccountReport()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I can't use DB. Will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

An idea could be, to load the data into a database and do the work in SQL. With Load-Table functions you can load a lot of data in a very short time.